# CMake: How to access a variable from a subdirectory without explicitly setting it in parent scope

Tags: cmake, box2d

I have added a subdirectory in `CMake` by using `add_subdirectory`. How can I access a variable from the scope of that subdirectory without explicitly setting the variable by using `set` in combination with `PARENT_SCOPE` ?

```
set(BOX2D_BUILD_STATIC       1)
set(BOX2D_BUILD_EXAMPLES     0)
set(BOX2D_INSTALL_BY_DEFAULT 0)

add_subdirectory(Box2D_v2.2.1)

message(STATUS "Using Box2D version ${BOX2D_VERSION}")

# how to get ${BOX2D_VERSION} variable without modifying CMakeLists.txt in Box2D_v2.2.1?
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How is the `BOX2D_VERSION` variable set in the subdirectory's CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: It is set as a plain variable. (so according to the answer below it seems like it is not possible to access it without modifying Bod2d's CMakeLists.txt)

Comment: Well, kinda.  I've added an answer which is more of a workaround than a true solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the variable is a plain variable (as opposed to a cache variable), there is no way to access it from the parent scope.

Cache variables (those set with `set(... CACHE ...)`) can be accessed regardless of scope, as can global properties (`set_property(GLOBAL ...)`).

Answer (score 2):

While @Angew's answer is correct, there aren't many things that are really *impossible* with CMake :-)

If you have a line like

```
set(BOX2D_VERSION 2.2.1)
```

in Box2D_v2.2.1/CMakeLists.txt, then you can retrieve the version in the parent scope by doing something like:

```
file(STRINGS Box2D_v2.2.1/CMakeLists.txt VersionSetter
     REGEX "^[ ]*set\\(BOX2D_VERSION")
string(REGEX REPLACE "(^[ ]*set\\(BOX2D_VERSION[ ]*)([^\\)]*)\\)" "\\2"
       BOX2D_VERSION ${VersionSetter})
```

This is a bit fragile; it doesn't accommodate for extra spaces in the `set` command for example, or cater for the value being set twice.  You could cater for these possibilities too, but if you know the format of the `set` command and it's unlikely to change, then this is a reasonable workaround.

Comment: Nice trick. I'd turn `[ ]` into `[ \t]`, just in case. Also, it won't work when the variable is set using a function (think `set(${resVar} 1.1 PARENT_SCOPE)`), inside a conditional etc. I like your answer, but there are a lot of caveats.

Comment: @Angew - Yeah, I agree that this is just a workaround - your's is definitely the best answer (it's got a +1 from me).  I think this could be adapted using regex matching to suit almost any scenario, but it quickly becomes massively complex and likely to be error-prone / not future-proof / etc.

Comment: And yours got +1 from me :-)